# How do security patches work with updated software packages?

Tags: security, updates, opensuse, patch

It seems like since I started updating packages on my system that there are fewer security patches to install. So I'm wondering if these incremental releases generally contain the security patches that would otherwise need to be applied to, say, the factory install.

Can you say something about how this works, at least in general? It seems like there would be security patches to base packages that would conflict with updates that have been applied to those packages.

Does updating the packages on a system thereafter make it difficult or impossible to get security patches and mean that the packages must thereafter be religiously updated rather than security patches being applied to them? This is just confusing to me.

My OS is openSUSE, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be of the opinion that a security update will only replace the affected parts of the package. This is not the the case.

In Linux, all updates received through the system package manager (Yum, Apt, Pacman etc.) replace the *entire* package.

So generally, if the package is using decent coding methodology and version control systems (e.g. Git), if an update is released that fixes a security flaw (for example, a point release where the version number after the decimal is incremented; `1.X`), and later an update is released that includes feature updates (a version release; `X.0`), the previous security fix(es) will be rolled into the latest version (notwithstanding the possibility of [regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)).

Comment: Wow. I've been wrong about this all along? Is it possible that `zypper` creates its own diff and patches binaries?

Comment: @TomRussell afraid I don’t know zypper at all.

Comment: Thanks. It must take a pretty strong Git knowledge to get this workflow correct for large, distributed projects. Regressions would tend to explode the brain.

Comment: On openSuse there's the concept of the `deltarpm`: https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.sw_cl.html#sec.rpm.delta